# Jar with mysql connection can not run

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jar

I have difficulty in compressing java package into jar. The program is a mini library manager using JDBC. I followed several tutorials but the jar generated is still can not run.

Here are some screenshots may be helpful.

[image: 111]

MANIFEST.MF:

[image: 222]

mysql connection jar:

[image: 333]

Procedure of export:

[image: 444] [image: 555] [image: 666]

Comment: What does "can not run" mean? How do you try to run the jar file?

Comment: Also, after you create the Jar file, can you go outside of the IDE and list the contents of your Jar file with the `jar -tf <filename>` and verify that it contains what you think it does?  Post the results of the output of that command here if there appears to be any problems.

Comment: @Andreas I just double click the jar file. It will alert after a few seconds telling me there are some problem with the jar file.

Comment: @markspace It does contain the expected files.
1.ex5/JDBCexample.class     
2. ex5/JDBCexample.java     
3. lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar

Comment: The `Class-Path` property of the MANIFEST.MF file causes Java to look for the `mysql-xxx.jar` file in a `lib` folder *next to* your generated jar file, not *inside* it. And if you run the program from the command-prompt, you might actually see a good error message.

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot! It doesn't have any error message when run from the command-prompt! I don't know why it is ok to run the program from the command-prompt when it is not by double click. This is my first java program actually. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Andreas! The right way to execute the jar is 'java -jar filename' rather than double click it.